# When to use `save` vs `save!` in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

According to [save bang your head, active record will drive you mad](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807850/save-bang-your-head-active-record-will-drive-you-mad), we should avoid using `save!` and `rescue` idiom for exceptional situations. Given that, say a model needs to `@post.mark_rejected`.

If the code in `mark_rejected` fails due to one of the below problems, should an exception be thrown? :

- if there is a validation problem
- if a non-nullable-field was being assigned a null
- if there was a connection loss to database

If we do not throw an exception, then:

- controller action would have to check for return value of `mark_rejected` and do it's thing
- we are not expecting an exception from that method call, so we do not write a `rescue` clause in the controller action, thus the exception bubbles up to (..wherever..) and will probably show up as some (500 HTTP?) error

Example code:

```
def mark_rejected
  ...
  save!
end
```

or

```
def mark_rejected
  ...
  save
end
```

Comment: @Zabba Here is the [source code and documentation of `save` and `save!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L86).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's more overhead in an exception, so there is a performance issue, especially when it can be expected that it will likely be thrown often, as is the case with `save`.

It is fewer lines of code to check if the return value is false than rescue an exception, so I don't see how it's a problem having to check for the return value if you already have to rescue the exception. How often would an exception thrown by `save!` ever have to bubble-up the call stack in practice? Rarely, if ever, in my experience.

If there is an exception thrown when calling `save` as opposed to `save!` you should want it to show a 500 error page because that's what happened: an unrecoverable, unknown, unexpected internal server error.

Comment: Thank you for all your help today.
I've read a bit about exceptions now, and have come to the conclusion that exceptions should not be used for
"flow control" so to speak. If there is an exception, I will let it bubble up the call stack and instead write
value-checking code to deal with problems. At the moment the approach seems the right way to do these things, though I'm not entirely sure 
of the reasons. Oh well.

Answer (score 210):

`save!` will raise an error if not successful.

`save` will return boolean value like true or false.

Comment: What is the opposite command for save! I mean what's the command for deleting the user?

Comment: `user.delete` and `user.remove` It will delete the user

Comment: @ram Right now activerecord does not have `remove?` method. I don't think so.

Comment: A `save` return value of `true` indicates success and `false` indicates an failure and `.errors` on the model would contain details.

Answer (score 11):

Suggestion: use `save` when it's on the last line; `save!` otherwise.

The idea: if the method is returning the save's result you should not throw exception and let the caller to handle save problems, but if the save is buried inside model method logic you would want to abort the process with an exception in case of failure.