# if @model.save is always true(by valid data and save to database or invalid data and doesn't save to database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want use `angularjs` in a rails application. For this, I post data from angularjs to rails server and then I want if server doesn't save data to database, I send errors from rails server to angularjs part. I use below code to do this work:

`bolouks_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    @bolouk = Bolouk.create(bolouk_params)
    if @bolouk.save #always true
      respond_with @bolouk, :location => api_bolouks_path
    else
      respond_with @bolouk.errors, :location => api_bolouks_path
    end
  end
```

`model/bolouk.rb`:

```
class Bolouk < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_length_of :south, :minimum => 5,  :presence => true
end
```

but when I post data to rails server, if data is invalid, **data doesn't save to database**, but I get **`Completed 201 Created in 32ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)`** in server log. I know the reason of this problem. ***`if @bolouk.save` statement is always true.***

`server log`:

```
Started POST "/api/bolouks.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-08 10:31:40 +0430
Processing by Api::V1::BolouksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"south"=>"", "bolouk"=>{"south"=>""}}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (1.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 201 Created in 37ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

I don't know why `if @bolouk.save` always true? How can I change `create` action code to optimize code and `.save` statement work correctly?` Any one have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: `@bolouk.save!` use a bang(`!`) sign

Comment: It's work. Whats diffrent between **`.save`** and **`.save!`**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056385/when-to-use-save-vs-save-in-model

Answer (score 1):

Anything with an exclamation with raise an error if it is not
successful

So `save!` instead of `save` to show your validation error

And your method will look like

```
def create
  @bolouk = Bolouk.create(bolouk_params)
  if @bolouk.save! 
    respond_with @bolouk, :location => api_bolouks_path
  else
    respond_with @bolouk.errors, :location => api_bolouks_path
  end
 end
```

To execute after error

```
def create
  begin
    @bolouk = Bolouk.create(bolouk_params)
    @bolouk.save! 
    respond_with @bolouk, :location => api_bolouks_path
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,  ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
    respond_with @bolouk.errors, :location => api_bolouks_path
  end
 end
```

Comment: I use this code, but when data is invalid, I get `500 Internal Error` and  `else` statement doesn't run and `errors` doesn't return to angularjs part.

Comment: if validation failed it will return error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid `

Comment: look at my post again to work after validation failed

Comment: if call back return false it will give  `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` exception

Comment: Your new answer work correctly with `.save` instead of `.save!`.

Comment: Change `@bolouk.save!` with `@bolouk.save` in your seccond answer, and then I mark it at correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the validation, please try this

```
validates :south, :length => {:minimum => 5}, :presence => true
```

or separate each validation:

```
validates_presence_of :south
validates_length_of   :south, minimum: 5
```

Comment: I use this validation, but again if statement is true.