# Rails Model Not Saving Correctly on Form Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model, controller

My model is not saving correctly, nor before the before_save validation I've written.

My form is below:

```
<%= form_for @troll, url: {action: 'create'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email (not stored)' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :required => true,  :prompt => 'Email Address' %><br/><br/>
    <%= f.label :apikey, 'API Key (not stored)' %>
    <%= f.text_field :apikey,:required => true, :prompt => 'API Key' %><br/><br/>
    <%= f.label :zone_id, 'Zone ID' %>
    <%= f.text_field :zone_id,:required => true,  :prompt => 'Zone Id' %></br><br/>
    <%= f.label :ip_addr, 'IPv4 Address' %>
    <%= f.text_field :ip_addr,:required => true, :prompt => 'IPv4 Address' %><br/><br/>
    <%= f.label :timeframe, 'Select a timeframe.' %>
    <%= f.select :timeframe, [["15 mins", 15],["60 mins", 60]] %><br/><br/>
    <%= f.submit troll_index_path, :value => "Commence Troll!" %>

<% end %>
```

The #create action:

```
  def create
    puts params[:troll]
    @troll = Troll.new(troll_params)
    @troll.save

    puts @troll.inspect

    render '/troll/show', :troll => @troll
   end
```

Farther down:

```
def troll_params
    params.require(:troll).permit(:email, :apikey, :zone_id, :ip_addr, :timeframe)
  end
```

My 'show' action and the terminal show:

```
#<Troll id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, ip_addr: "aaa", zone_id: nil, unix_timestamp: nil>
```

So the info is not being saved nor validated. My model is below:

```
class Troll < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'resolv'

    attr_accessor :apikey, :email, :zone_id, :unix_timestamp, :time_interval, :timeframe

    validates :ip_addr, :format => {:with => Resolv::IPv4::Regex,:message => "Not an valid IPv4 format"}

    before_save :convert_to_unix

    def convert_to_unix(time_interval)
      timeValue = self.time_interval.to_i
      timeStamp = DateTime.now - timeValue/1440.0
      self.unix_timestamp = timeStamp.to_i 
    end

end
```

My DB Schema is really simple. I'm only interested in saving a few pieces of data for privacy reasons.

```
class CreateTrolls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :trolls do |t|

      t.string :ip_addr
      t.string :zone_id
      t.integer :unix_timestamp

    end
  end
end
```

I see the params come across correctly, but when I save to the DB it's not validating the ip_attr or peforming the unix timestamp transformation.

It's also showing zone_id as nil even though it's right there in the params! Any direction much appreciated.

Comment: what does your schema file look like?

Comment: Hey @AndrewHendrie, I've added it above. Cheers.

Comment: are you using strong params in your trolls controller?

Comment: Yes. I believe so. Just added that above.

Comment: Will you do me a favour and fix the syntax here: `<%= f.text_field :zone_id,:required => true,  :prompt => 'Zone Id' %></br><br/>`. The breaks at the end are wrong: `<br/></br>`. I doubt it but let me know if anything changes.

Comment: Also, run `@troll.save!` and see what error is returned: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27421738/1945948 .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your submit button to this:

```
f.submit "Commence Troll"
```

Comment: It does the same thing. I get zone_id as nil in the my show view, but the params still show zone_id with a value.

Comment: Try removing the attr_accessor line in your model?

Comment: That will bomb out because I need to access the email,apikey variables, but I do not wish to store them.

Comment: have you tested it without resolv and/or without the convert_to_unix method?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best using the following:

```
#app/views/trolls/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @troll do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email, 'Email (not stored)' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :required => true,  :prompt => 'Email Address' %>

    <%= f.label :apikey, 'API Key (not stored)' %>
    <%= f.text_field :apikey, required: true, placeholder: 'API Key' %>

    <%= f.label :zone_id, 'Zone ID' %>
    <%= f.text_field :zone_id, required: true, placeholder: 'Zone Id' %>

    <%= f.label :ip_addr, 'IPv4 Address' %>
    <%= f.text_field :ip_addr, required: true, placeholder: 'IPv4 Address' %>

    <%= f.label :timeframe, 'Select a timeframe.' %>
    <%= f.select :timeframe, [["15 mins", 15],["60 mins", 60]] %><br/><br/>
    <%= f.submit "Commence Troll!" %>

<% end %>


#app/controllers/trolls_controller.rb
class TrollsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @troll = Troll.new troll_params
      redirect_to @troll if @troll.save
   end

   private

   def troll_params
      params.require(:troll).permit(:email, :apikey, :zone_id, :ip_addr, :timeframe)
   end
end


#app/models/troll.rb
class Troll < ActiveRecord::Base
   require 'resolv'

   attr_accessor :apikey, :email, :time_interval, :timeframe
   validates :ip_addr, format: { with: Resolv::IPv4::Regex, message: "Not an valid IPv4 format"}

   before_save :convert_to_unix

   private

   def convert_to_unix(time_interval)
      timeValue           = self.time_interval.to_i
      timeStamp           = DateTime.now - timeValue/1440.0
      self.unix_timestamp = timeStamp.to_i 
   end
end
```

--

You had `:zone_id` & `unix_timestamp` in the `attr_accessor` declaration, meaning they would not get saved.

If you run the above code, it should return to your `trolls#new` action if any errors occur, allowing you to resolve them.